# GoogleMaps Android API MyLocation issue

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have app that use GoogleMaps API and have faced an issue that tap on myLocationButton do nothing. So the button is visible, I see my location, but when I click on button it doesn't center camera on y location. This is my code:

1) Fragment with map:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRetainInstance(true);
    mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.onCreate(null);
    MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());

    mMap = mapView.getMap();
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    UISettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
    UISettings.setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
    UISettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}
```

2) XML with map:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:slidingLayer="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: CameraUpdate zoom=CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);

    map.moveCamera(center);
    map.animateCamera(zoom); use this

Comment: Sometimes it won't move until it gets a location with some accuracy and then automatically will move the camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried and you can use following code that I have used, it works fine:

1) Fragment with map:

MapView mapView;

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mapview, container, false);
    // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it

    MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());


    switch (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity())) {
        case ConnectionResult.SUCCESS:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.map);
            mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
            if (mapView != null) {
                 mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
                        googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                    }
                });

            }
            break;
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_MISSING:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SERVICE MISSING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "UPDATE REQUIRED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return v;
}
```

2) XML with map:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name=".YOUR_FRAGMENT_NAME_HERE"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that you need change the `android:name=".YOUR_FRAGMENT_NAME_HERE"` to your fragment name above. At this point you should good to go:)

Comment: Thanks, but it works okay while we have MapView. The point was that I'm trying to use Fragment, and there is an exception...

Comment: The code I provided is for fragment, you can just embed it in a fragment. What kind of exception you get?

Comment: I get NullPointer after getMap() in mMap.

Comment: I didn't get null pointer exception in my case, but I edited my code according to [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/reference/com/google/android/m4b/maps/MapView.html#getMap()) says that getMap is deprecated, so I use `getMapAsync` instead. you can check my edited answer.

Comment: Does this helped you? If so, please accept. If not please tell me, thanks

Comment: I've solved this issue another way. But this was helpful, so thank you and I'll also accept it.